# Replace the default virtual keyboard by a custom keyboard in android's webview

Tags: javascript, android, webview, keyboard, android-softkeyboard

I want to write an Android application using WebView to display a web page.

This web page has already a keyboard for edit text fields (i.e., search box).

How can I replace this default keyboard by my own one?

Fox example, how can I edit text in the search box of this web page by my keyboard? I'm very grateful for someone can help on this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please [edit] your question to show [the code you have so far](http://whathaveyoutried.com).  You should include at least an outline (but preferably a [mcve]) of the code that you are having problems with, then we can try to help with the specific problem. You should also read [ask].